In draft mode listpage is not refreshed on closing create Object flow
PopupThe normal flow of creating draft mode and then hitting the Create button in footer is creating new object and also refereshing the List page.
However when in draft mode when we try to close the object and in the pop-up if we choose Create - Create new object and then click on Ok it is observed that list page is not refreshed with latest values.
Internally we also observed that it uses same code EditFflow.ts > saveDocument
Steps to Reproduce

Click on Create button List page
Fill the necessary details in draft mode
Now try to close the details object page. (close button on top right corner)
Now a pop-up open asking 3 options - Choose Create option and click on ok

UI5 version - 1.125.1
When closing the object page in draft mode (in which object is not created yet) and when we choose the Create option in popup, expectation is once the entitiy is saved it should also refresh the List page. Similar to normal flow of creating object using Create button in footer.
